# How to avoid runtime loading of googlemap api Javascript- phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a phonegap app which uses google maps to show directions and user location. I have used the default google api by adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

I have observed this causes the app initialization to slow down, and sometimes even crash if connectivity is slow on the mobile device. I understand that the app will not start unless all the scripts are loaded.

I tried downloading the JavaScript from the url http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false and storing locally, but that makes the map loading fail at times.

Is there an equivalent script which can be stored in the app itself? or can we delay the loading of script after the app is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the API asynchronously, as it is done on [**this example**](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async). Like that you can decide, within your javascript, when to load it, (call to loadScript()), and initialize the map after that.

Note that the example uses a callback parameter, which is the name of a function to call when loading of the API is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java script asynchronous process. This method based on callback response.

Google maps javascript api provide for asynchronous loading [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async)

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```