# Phonegap android app in 3g or 2g connection index.html loading very slow

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

On 3g and 2g connection we have very slow load of the page,and if there is an issue during the page load with a connection the page hung altogether. Without killing or in some cases re-installing the app, I wasn't able to get logged in.

Whats confusing about this problem is it doesn't happen on ios . I don't understand why there is such a difference.

Thanks

Lokesh

Comment: the index.html should be stored inside the phone, it can be opened without internet connection, so the problem is what did you do with the connection inside index.html, is it done Before deviceready or after deviceready?  did you use async for connection related codes?  ios has a setting to display contents before everything is done.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth Li ,will try with your suggestion :)

Comment: @Kenneth Li  Based upon your suggestion, i have called the onDeiceReady function first then call other functions, in this case found the native webview does not render the index.html file for slow connection and hence i can only see a white screen coming up  …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java script asynchronous process for adding java script file dynamically.

```
function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'http://test.com/js'; //url of java script file.
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

When we load phonegap app in low network then server based java script file not load with the help of asynchronous task we can load all file dynamically if network available or not.

Please follow : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216382/how-to-avoid-runtime-loading-of-googlemap-api-javascript-phonegap/30505935#30505935)